# Create PDF document in SQL

Tags: t-sql, pdf, sp-send-dbmail, dbmail

I am writing a stored procedure in T-SQL that sends mail. I am looking to add an attachment to these emails. I have an html string that I would like to convert to pdf and attach to my email.

I am using selectPDF to convert my html to pdf.

Can this all be done in sql or do I have to write an application for creating the pdf document?

Comment: you probably ***could*** do it with a complicated CLR proc that was written in asp.net. But at that point you're writing it in ASP.net in a more complicated manner than it would be just to do it via a process that didn't involve sql email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had good luck with iTextSharp in the past.  [iTextSharp Project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

You would be looking at a wrapper CLR function around that, but yes it can be done.

As a side note too you could also design a SSRS report and automate that too...

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help.